# The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<TimelineItem>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I can use it directly without joining async, but return items to items in DynamicTimeline without finishing execution,

```
    final items = [
      TimelineItem(
        startDateTime: DateTime(1973, 1, 1, 8, 30),
        endDateTime: DateTime(1973, 1, 1, 9, 55),
        child: const Event(title: '占位课程'),
      ),
    ];
Future<List<TimelineItem>> loadItems(DateTime date) async {
DateTime firstWeek = DateTime(2022, 9, 5);

      int week = date.difference(firstWeek).inDays ~/ 7 + 1;
      int weekday = date.weekday;    
      getCourseInfo().then((value) {
        List courseList = value.split('},');
        items.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < courseList.length; i++) {
          if (courseList[i].contains('zc":$week') &&
              courseList[i].contains('xq":$weekday')) {
            if (courseList[i].contains('jc":"0102')) {
              items.add(TimelineItem(
                startDateTime: DateTime(1971, 1, 1, 8, 30),
                endDateTime: DateTime(1971, 1, 1, 9, 55),
                child: Event(
                  title: 
                      courseList[i].substring(
                          courseList[i].indexOf('coursename":"') + 12,
                          courseList[i].indexOf('","teacher"')),
                ),
              ));
            }
      });
      return items;
    }
```

```
SingleChildScrollView(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
child: DynamicTimeline(
firstDateTime: DateTime(1971, 1, 1, 8, 30),
lastDateTime: DateTime(1971, 1, 1, 22, 30),
labelBuilder: DateFormat('HH:mm').format,
intervalDuration: const Duration(hours: 2),
maxCrossAxisItemExtent: 200,
intervalExtent: 80,
minItemDuration: const Duration(minutes: 30),
items: getCourseInfo()),
),
```

[Items only receives List < TimelineItem >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a79Tf.png)

```
Items only receives List < TimelineItem >
```

I would like to ask if I can only return items after all the code in loadItems has been executed.

Comment: Try changing the items instantiation from `final items = [];` to `final items = <TimelineItem>[];`. This way, atleast you could find where string is messing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<List<TimelineItem>> loadItems(DateTime date) async {
    final items = <TimelineItem>[];
    DateTime firstWeek = DateTime(2022, 9, 5);
    int week = date.difference(firstWeek).inDays ~/ 7 + 1;
    int weekday = date.weekday;
    final value = await getCourseInfo();
    List courseList = value.split('},');
    for (int i = 0; i < courseList.length; i++) {
      if (courseList[i].contains('zc":$week') &&
          courseList[i].contains('xq":$weekday')) {
        if (courseList[i].contains('jc":"0102')) {
          items.add(TimelineItem(
            startDateTime: DateTime(1971, 1, 1, 8, 30),
            endDateTime: DateTime(1971, 1, 1, 9, 55),
            child: Event(
              title: courseList[i].substring(
                  courseList[i].indexOf('coursename":"') + 12,
                  courseList[i].indexOf('","teacher"')),
            ),
          ));
        }
      }
    }
    return items;
  }
```

*******BAD code*******
i  think that error  from another place, not from this one